# Can a Force Apex application call external webservices?

Tags: salesforce, force.com

If I build an application in the Force platform can it call an external webservice? Lets say a user adds the Force application from the App Exchange, will they get prompted to allow the web service access?

Answer (score 5):

A calling external web services is built-in functionality of Force.com platform. You can read about it in the following [doc](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts)

Within force.com platform you have 2 options:

- Use [HTTP (RESTful) Services Classes](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_classes_restful.htm)
- User [SOAP Services](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex.htm) (Force.com provides tool wsdl2apex, which is similar to wsdl2java )